# SDL 2.0 -> Passed a NULL mutex

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

When I'm compiling a simple example with SDL 2.0, after the command SDL_CreateWindow, this occurring the following error: "Passed a NULL mutex".

I'm using the static library project. Also I'm testing on OSX 10.8.3.

This inform missing something on the command line compilation?

Below is the command line to generate the program generation and code example.

Compiler:

```
clang++ -I "TestSDL/sdl/include" -Wall -c -x c++ -arch x86_64 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -MMD -MP -MF"src/main.d" -MT"src/main.d" -o "src/main.o" "../src/main.cpp"
```

Linker:

```
clang++ -L "TestSDL/sdl/lib" -arch x86_64 -stdlib=libc++ -Bstatic -framework GLUT -framework ForceFeedBack -framework IOKit -framework CoreAudio -framework CoreFoundation -framework Carbon -framework AudioUnit -framework AudioToolbox -framework OpenGL -framework Cocoa -o "TestSDL" ./src/main.o -lSDL2
```

Code:

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void checkSDLError(int line = -1)
{
    const char *error = SDL_GetError();

    if (*error != '\0') {
        cout << "SDL Error: " << error << " line: " << line << endl;
        SDL_ClearError();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) {
        return false;
    }

    SDL_Window * window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test SDL", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 512, 512,
            SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    checkSDLError(__LINE__);

    if (!window) {
        cout << "Unable to create window" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Event event;
    while (true) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    return 1;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

Comment: When did this occur, what did you change?

Comment: How telling, occurs after the command `SDL_CreateWindow` and is verified with the function `checkSDLError` . And I would like to fix this problem, however I have not found information about it. Or if this is really a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In conversation with the list (SDL http://lists.libsdl.org/listinfo.cgi/sdl-libsdl.org), I was informed in the same way that phpBoing reported.
How have had several reports of this problem recently, an adjustment was made (http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/rev/f8e3dcefed59) for this problem no longer occurs.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

Your doing it wrong.
You should **only** call checkSDLError() **if** window == NULL.

http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.fcg/SDL_CreateWindow

> Returns the window that was created or NULL on failure; call SDL_GetError() for more information.

Comment: ok, however when it is possible to verify errors at any time, in this case I ended up doing without checking, however I returned an error.